# How does uniq work?

Tags: command-line, sort, uniq

Do not confuse this question to be a duplicate of "what is difference b/w sort -u and sort | uniq"

This is in essence a word count program

Confusion raised from the following command is reason for asking this question:

```
    root@sanctum:~/datascience# cat data 
    this is a file that is supposed to be a file
```

this gives incorrect output:

```
root@sanctum:~/datascience# cat data | sed 's/ /\n/g' | uniq -c
      1 this
      1 is
      1 a
      1 file
      1 that
      1 is
      1 supposed
      1 to
      1 be
      1 a
      1 file
```

Piping the output to sort and then to uniq gives the perfect answer-

```
root@sanctum:~/datascience# cat data | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort |uniq -c
      2 a
      1 be
      2 file
      2 is
      1 supposed
      1 that
      1 this
      1 to
```

output of when piped just to sort:

```
root@sanctum:~/datascience# cat data | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort 
a
a
be
file
file
is
is
supposed
that
this
to
```

how does the line number of appearance of a line have an effect on the count of the occurrences in the file? *i dont know how to phrase it but u get the point*

Basically why cant `cat data | sed 's/ /\n/g' | uniq -c` give the required result?

Answer (score 3):

This is not random behavior. From [`man uniq`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/uniq.1.html):

> **Note**:  'uniq'  does  not  detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.  You may want to sort the input first, or use 'sort -u' without 'uniq'.  Also, comparisons honor the rules specified by 'LC_COLLATE'.

Essentially, `uniq` by default only works on **sorted** input. It is so by design, in other words.

Your main question however is:

> how does the line number of appearance of a line have an effect on the count of the occurrences in the file

To answer this question, you'd really have to look at [uniq](https://www.maizure.org/projects/decoded-gnu-coreutils/uniq.html)'s [source code](https://github.com/MaiZure/coreutils-8.3/blob/d75fc70b777414bb735ac9ec4f39ae9405a849ee/src/uniq.c#L371):

```c
while (!feof (stdin))
  {
    char *thisfield;
    size_t thislen;
    if (readlinebuffer_delim (thisline, stdin, delimiter) == 0)
      break;
    thisfield = find_field (thisline);
    thislen = thisline->length - 1 - (thisfield - thisline->buffer);
    if (prevline->length == 0
        || different (thisfield, prevfield, thislen, prevlen))
      {
        fwrite (thisline->buffer, sizeof (char),
                thisline->length, stdout);

        SWAP_LINES (prevline, thisline);
        prevfield = thisfield;
        prevlen = thislen;
      }
  }
```

The key here is that the file is read **line-by-line** and comparison can be done only with current and previous line in the function `different()` which returns True if lines are not the same, False if they are the same. The reason for that really is that if you were to compare against *all* lines, you'd probably need a large amount of memory if there's a large number of lines. This isn't practical, and would slow down `uniq` considerably